# Firebase dataSnapshot how to access values

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

i have a firebase datasnaphot.value that currently returns

{adawd33={uid=Y2CFDEkOPWSConzoufKtzvZojYP2, password=wwadada33, email=duncboidev@gmail.com, username=adawd33}}

```
  override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d("Login", "${snapshot.value}")
```

how do i manipulate the snapshot to just return the parent val "adwad33" as a string?

Comment: From what I can see adawd33 is the name of a nested child of this snapshot with several other children of its own, including a password of the same name.  What exactly are you hoping to get?  Just the name of the one nested child?

Comment: yes just the name of the nested child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access children with an unknown key, you'll loop over `DataSnapshot.children`.

To access children with a known name, you use `child(...)`.

Combining these:

```
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
  for (childSnapshot: snapshot.children) {
    Log.d("Login", childSnapshot.key);
    Log.d("Login", childSnapshot.child("uid").getValue<String>());
  }
}
```

Comment: now how do i change the uid value in the database to something else using this snapshot value?

Comment: nvm i figured it out